# Get all touches without UIEvent

Tags: iphone, uitouch

I'm looking for a way to get all the current touches even if no event has occurred. I know about `[UIEvent allTouches]` but I need to be able to see "these are all the touches on the screen" even if none of them has changed. It seems like it should be possible because `allTouches` can access touches which haven't been updated, so the phone is tracking them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override touchesBegan and touchesEnded, and compare the current point against the cached point from the event.

Comment: Note that I had no current point to compare with. I simply used `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` to maintain a cache of touch locations and referred to that when necessary.

Comment: What about touchesCancelled? Also, touchesEnded is not always called.

Answer (score 0):

Try hitTest:withEvent and filter with pointInside:withEvent.

Comment: hitTest will tell me which view a point is in. I want a set of all the touches on the screen. Unless I've misunderstood something.

Comment: I generally hitTest with pointInside to determine the coordinates the user touches on the top most view when a component is being finicky in the responder chain (like with nested scrollviews, custom GUI widgets, etc) 

The [UIEvent allTouches] returns an array of all the touches (UITouch) the API wants available to you. What you want is access to the internal state of the last system UITouch? 

I think the best you will be able to do is access touchesBegan and touchesEnded, and cache a UITouch compare them yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid I'd have to do it myself, just seems silly they don't open it up to you.

Comment: Seems the best thing to do is cache the points as you said. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it.